# Regex replace in a 3GB file on CentOS Linux

Tags: linux, regex

I have a log file in the following format

```
[2016-10-18 00:00:04 UTC] user1: hello
[2016-10-18 00:00:05 UTC] user2: hey user
[2016-10-18 00:00:07 UTC] user3: bye
```

and I want it to be in this format

```
[2016-10-18 00:00:04] <user1> hello
[2016-10-18 00:00:05] <user2> hey user
[2016-10-18 00:00:07] <user3> bye
```

This was pretty simple with the Regex replace in Notepad++ on Windows, however now I face a greater log of 3 Gigabytes in size, and I want to do this on a VPS.

Since the VPS will be running CentOS, what's the best way to do this regex replace?

```
Find:     UTC] (\w+):
Replace with:    ] <$1>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some long trial and error, and a lot of 'why isn't this working?!' I found that sed works  for me here

```
sed "s/ UTC] \([[:alnum:]]\+\):/] <\1>/g" log.txt > parsed.txt
```